# Cannot run Ettercap in Debian (GTK+ Failed to initialize. Is X running?)

Tags: debian, networking, x11, software-installation

I've installed ettercap-graphical on a fresh debian install.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
root@debian:/home/debian# sudo ettercap -G

ettercap 0.8.2 copyright 2001-2015 Ettercap Development Team

No protocol specified

GTK+ failed to initialize. Is X running?
```

Searching online, the solution [here](https://github.com/Ettercap/ettercap/issues/815) (second last comment) says to run `xhost local:root`. 
However that gives me an error:

```
root@debian:/home/debian# xhost local:root
No protocol specified
xhost: unable to open display ":0"
```

Researching that error, solutions such as setting `DISPLAY` variable to `127.0.0.1:10.0` or `<ipaddress>:0.0` (where ip address is my machine's ip), do not work. It just changes the error to `unable to open display ":10.0"`.

I've tried setting the DISPLAY variable all combinations of: `(ip address/127.0.01):(10.0/11.0/0.0)`.

Comment: Your prompt shows you running `sudo` while already root; try dropping the `sudo`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Same error for both commands without the 'sudo'

Comment: Do you have a graphical session started somewhere?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes I am doing this from a terminal, but the OS is graphical. There is only one session

Comment: Did you start the session as root, or another user?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I started the session as another user then used the `su` command to go to root, as my other user is not in the sudoers file

Comment: It seems valuable to me to describe that sequence in your question.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I ran `xhost local:root` on my non-root user without sudo, and it worked! Thanks for your help. I didn't realize the type of user mattered, I'm new to linux / any OS administration. Thanks again

Comment: @JeffSchaller BTW This question reached 2,500 views. You've most likely helped a lot of people with this issue, not just myself :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution from the [Ettercap wiki](https://github.com/Ettercap/ettercap/wiki/X-DISPLAY-issue-with-sudo) on github:

> ## X issue when ettercap is started with sudo and GTK UI
>
> Solution
>
> There is a easy fix to this issue. **Run the following command in the user's context**.
>
> ```
> $ xhost local:root
> ```

You need to execute the above command as user.

Comment: Your question suggests that you tried running the `xhost` command as root. You need to run it as the user (`debian`, apparently). You also need to use the original value of `DISPLAY`.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks, running `xhost local:root` as my regular user worked & I can now run Ettercap in graphical mode!

Comment: BTW This question just reached 2,500 views. You guys most likely helped a lot of people with this issue, not just myself :-) @StephenKitt